# Copy into system clipboard from neovim

Tags: lua, windows-subsystem-for-linux, copy-paste, neovim

I just started using neovim and I am having issues trying to copy codes from neovim to system clipboard. I wanted to share some line of code and I am unable to copy the code into the system clipbooard.

I have tried lots of solutions. I have zero knowledge on lua. I copied a config file i liked and that is what I am using so i don't know what I am doing.
Some of the things I have tried is installing win32yank,

```
vim.cmd [[
    let g:clipboard = {
      \   'name': 'win32yank-wsl',
      \   'copy': {
      \      '+': 'win32yank.exe -i --crlf',
      \      '*': 'win32yank.exe -i --crlf',
      \    },
      \   'paste': {
      \      '+': 'win32yank.exe -o --lf',
      \      '*': 'win32yank.exe -o --lf',
      \   },
      \   'cache_enabled': 0,
      \ }
]]
```

I have also tried

```
let g:clipboard = {
    \   'name': 'WslClipboard',
    \   'copy': {
    \      '+': 'clip.exe',
    \      '*': 'clip.exe',
    \    },
    \   'paste': {
    \      '+': 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
    \      '*': 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
    \   },
    \   'cache_enabled': 0,
    \ }
```

Like i said ealier, I don't know what i am doing. I need help please.

Comment: Doyoudo also: ```set clipboard=unnamedplus``` ? - As described in: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#how-to-use-the-windows-clipboard-from-wsl

Comment: Or `vim.opt.clipboard = 'unnamed'` in lua

Comment: Or `vim.api.nvim_set_option("clipboard", "unnamed")`

Answer (score 8):

I guess you are using lua but the problem is that both the snippets you shared are in vim script.

First of all, check if yank/paste is setup to use system clipboard or not. Add this to your config to enable yanking/pasting on system clipboard directly:

- If you are using init.lua, then add `vim.opt.clipboard = "unnamedplus"`.
- Incase of init.vim, add `set clipboard+=unnamedplus`.

## WSL

Since we are on WSL, there are couple of things we need to take care before setting up clipboard:

1. Remove `xclip` from your system if already installed. It is known to cause problems with WSL.
2. We also need to take care of line endings (CRLF->LF) when pasting on Neovim. we can use `sed` to remove all occurences of `/r`(CR) at the end of the line.

Now we have two options for copy-pasting across Linux and Windows:

#### WSLg (Fast)

Here, we rely on WSLg to sync Linux (Wayland) system clipboard with Windows one.
*Make sure **wl-clipboard** is installed on your system. and WSLg is enabled*. You can check if wslg is enabled by running following command and checking if WSLg version is shown or not:

```bash
$ wsl.exe --version
WSL version: 1.2.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51                   
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.1778
```

Finally, add following lines to your `init.lua`:

```lua
if vim.fn.has("wsl") == 1 then
    if vim.fn.executable("wl-copy") == 0 then
        print("wl-clipboard not found, clipboard integration won't work")
    else
        vim.g.clipboard = {
            name = "wl-clipboard (wsl)",
            copy = {
                ["+"] = 'wl-copy --foreground --type text/plain',
                ["*"] = 'wl-copy --foreground --primary --type text/plain',
            },
            paste = {
                ["+"] = (function()
                    return vim.fn.systemlist('wl-paste --no-newline|sed -e "s/\r$//"', {''}, 1) -- '1' keeps empty lines
                end),
                ["*"] = (function() 
                    return vim.fn.systemlist('wl-paste --primary --no-newline|sed -e "s/\r$//"', {''}, 1)
                end),
            },
            cache_enabled = true
        }
    end
end
```

#### Calling Windows commands from WSL (slow)

This works regardless of whether WSLg is enabled or not.

1. Download `win32yank.exe` from [here](https://github.com/equalsraf/win32yank/releases) or use following commands:

```bash
curl -sLo/tmp/win32yank.zip https://github.com/equalsraf/win32yank/releases/download/v0.1.1/win32yank-x64.zip
unzip -p /tmp/win32yank.zip win32yank.exe > /tmp/win32yank.exe
chmod +x /tmp/win32yank.exe
sudo mv /tmp/win32yank.exe /usr/local/bin/
```

2. make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in `$PATH`.
3. Add following to `init.lua`:

```lua
vim.g.clipboard = {
    name = 'win32yank-wsl',
    copy = {
        ['+'] =  'win32yank.exe -i --crlf',
        ['*'] =  'win32yank.exe -i --crlf',
    },
    paste = {
        ['+'] = 'win32yank.exe -o --lf',
        ['*'] = 'win32yank.exe -o --lf',
    },
    cache_enabled = true,
}
```

Happy Vimming!

Comment: Been using win32yank for sometime now and I want to test wl-clipboard but got an error. `A requied protocol  (zwlr_data_control_manager_v1 version1) is not supported by the compositor`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The above error is when `wl-clipboard-rs` is used, I tried to install `wl-clipboard` not rust implementation and got different error. `The compositor does not seem to support primary selection`

Comment: @zer09 I think you've set `vim.opt.clipboard = "unnamed"`, which should be set to `"unnamedplus"` Without it, nvim will use `wl-copy --foreground --primary --type text/plain` because we set it to `[*]` aka primary selection, which Wayland (core) doesn't support per [this comment](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/12452#issuecomment-643847770). There's more details on why you should use `wl-clipboard` [here](https://github.com/YaLTeR/wl-clipboard-rs/issues/8)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows. So the code below might help.
Here is what I use in my init.lua file.
It map the yank operation for example [yy] to ["+yy],the ["+yy] means using ["+] register perform [yy] operation. ["+] register is the register that direct interact with system clipboard.

```
-- set system clipboard
vim.keymap.set('n','y','"+y')
vim.keymap.set('n','yy','"+yy')
vim.keymap.set('n','Y','"+Y')
vim.keymap.set('x','y','"+y')
vim.keymap.set('x','Y','"+Y')
```