# Copy into system clipboard from neovim using wl-clipboard (WSL2)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, clipboard, neovim, wsl-2, neovim-plugin

i tried [this tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75548458/copy-into-system-clipboard-from-neovim/76388417#76388417) to use wl-clipboard but it doesnt work. FYI, my current nvim setup use the `win32yank` on a WSL2 Ubuntu. However, it was sluggish. that's why i'm looking for other method that is way faster.

here is my lua code for the wl-clipboard copied from that link above.

```lua
vim.opt.clipboard = "unnamedplus" 
if vim.fn.has("wsl") == 1 then
  if vim.fn.executable("wl-copy") == 0 then
    print("wl-clipboard not found, clipboard integration won't work")
  else
    vim.g.clipboard = {
      name = "wl-clipboard (wsl)",
      copy = {
        ["+"] = "wl-copy --foreground --type text/plain",
        ["*"] = "wl-copy --foreground --primary --type text/plain",
      },
      paste = {
        ["+"] = function()
          return vim.fn.systemlist('wl-paste --no-newline|sed -e "s/\r$//"', { "" }, 1) -- '1' keeps empty lines
        end,
        ["*"] = function()
          return vim.fn.systemlist('wl-paste --primary --no-newline|sed -e "s/\r$//"', { "" }, 1)
        end,
      },
      cache_enabled = true,
    }
  end
end
```

```bash
wsl-exe. --version
```

the command above return a value below.

```bash
WSL version: 2.0.14.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.3007
```

my nvim version

```bash
NVIM v0.10.0-dev
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
```

has anybody make the wl-clipboard to work?